# how do i detect tap gestures when the phone is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, lockscreen, uitapgesturerecognizer

The default alarm application by apple shows me a snooze button even when the phone is in lock screen and i can press it,so instead of a small button i want to create a larger button or something that will detect a multi touch when a alarm rings,is it possible? can the default lock screen be customized? thanks

Comment: You mean when the screen is black?

Comment: @H2CO3 i mean when a notification or an alarm arrives..i dont need tap gesture recognition every time,that is the reason they made lock screen i suppose

Comment: @sin Does this go in an AppStore app? You could try messing with the runtime or UIView to grab the toplevel window and experiment with it...

Comment: hmm i understand Appstore want allow me to mess with the toplevel window,i guess i have to drop the idea,anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only thing you can get in the lock screen is a push or local notification.  This has the default functionality of displaying your app's icon next to some text.  You can then slide the icon to launch the app with any extra data you attached to the notification when you created

Comment: how does apple allow you to touch the snooze button without unlocking the screen? i mean it says slide to view,but it also provides a button for snooze,did you notice it?

Comment: Because the alarm app is an apple application, they have access to private APIs that general developers are not allowed to use

Comment: oh ok..so i cant customize the snooze button,i have no access to it whatsoever?

Comment: ok great thanks,i accept your answer